# Doctrine Merge Entities partially

Tags: doctrine

I encounter a small issue with Doctrine.

When a user updates an entry, I create a new object with the same ID as the existing one and I merge them in order to update the latter. It works but the thing is that when I create a new object, in the constructor I set the value of the "date_created" to the current timestamp.

So when I merge the new entity it also updates the "date_created" field, which is supposed to stay unchanged. Is there a way to merge while ignoring the "date_created" field or should I just make a regular update query ?

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: Why are you merging the entities? If you load the original object anyway, why not update it directly? Maybe you could show some code to make it easier to see what exactly happens and how best to solve the issue based on your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code :

**Controller**

```
// Validation of user inputs

// New object with the ID of the existing one
         $newFetcher = new Fetcher(
                    $request->input('id'),
                    $request->input('name'),
                    $request->input('vendorOID'),
                    $request->input('productOID'),
                    $request->input('versionOID'),
                    $request->input('updateOID')
          );
// Calling repository to merge entities
$updatedFetcher = $this->q->update($newFetcher);
```

**Repository**

```
public function update(Fetcher $fetcher)
    {
        $this->_em->merge($fetcher);
        $this->_em->flush();
        return $fetcher;
    }
```

**A sample of the entity class**

```
public function __construct($id = 1, $name = "", $vendor_oid = null, $product_oid = null, $version_oid = null, $update_oid = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->vendor_oid = $vendor_oid;
        $this->product_oid = $product_oid;
        $this->version_oid = $version_oid;
        $this->update_oid = $update_oid;
        parent::setDateCreated();
        parent::setTimestamp();
    }
```

NB: all my entities extend from a super class for common fields such as ID, timestamp, date_created which I dont want to declare for each table.

setTimestamp and setdatecreated set the date of last update and the date of creation to the current timestamp :

**Superclass**

```
public function setTimestamp()
    {
        $this->timestamp = $this->getDateTime();
    }
public function setDateCreated()
    {
        $this->date_created = $this->getDateTime();
    }

public function getDateTime($tz = TIMEZONE)
    {
        return new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz));
    }
```